# Value cannot be null

Tags: visual-studio-2010, warnings

VS 2010 is reporting this warning "Value cannot be null". However, the project seems to be compiling fine. It doesn't show any other information that shows why this happening. I'm developing a project to run on Microsoft Robotics Studio.

Description: "Value cannot be null"

File: ** dssproxy

How can I find more information regarding this warning ?

The code is 3000+ lines. So I'm not sure if its worth posting here.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Q: How can I find more information regarding this error?  A: You could give *us* a bit more information - starting with the code that generated the warning ;)

Comment: Usually, when Visual Studio produces a warning or error, it shows the line number. Does it show the line number in your case? If yes, please show us the method containing the error and mark the faulty line. If no, a screenshot of the error would be nice.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. Unfortunately, as it shows it doesnt display any line numbers. Im thinking whether i should perhaps try and recreate the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions.

In the end it was a **missing namespace** on one of the files i have added as a Link. Perhaps why dssproxy.exe was complaining. Wasn't very obvious by "Value cannot be null" though.

Wouldn't have been able to figure it out had I not started from scratch :(.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is sometimes caused by adding code for a control on your form, then deleting the control and leaving the code.  Try commneting code for once so that you will get idea what exactly is causing this error.

Check this link which discussed the same:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/dbe2e211-2263-4dee-8e0d-428cabe8119b/

Another possible reason is that you can receive this error when you are creating your component or control on the design surface from the Toolbox. The most likely cause is that you are trying to use a component or control that was built to a 64-bit assembly. The Visual Studio design environment does not support 64-bit components.

Comment: Yeah i have come across that post as well. Only problem is I'm not using any winforms in the code. Its a bunch of C# classes.

Comment: @kuzyt Is it 64-bit components?